# Concerns with using TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, modelstate, tempdata

I'm using TempData to persist ModelState errors for a form which is rendered from a ChildAction.  The form allows a user to post a comment on a blog post.  If the ModelState isn't valid, the errors are copied to TempData and I redirect to my `ShowPost` action which displays the comment form, complete with validation errors, via the ChildAction.

My concern is that I'm actually redirecting twice in between saving the ModelState errors to TempData and redisplaying them in the ChildAction.  This is because in my `ShowPost` action, I'm also checking to see if there is a valid slug matching the current post and then redirecting to include that slug if it's missing/incorrect.  That means if a user posts a comment, they post to:

```
/posts/comment
```

which will redirect to:

```
/posts/1/
```

and then redirect to:

```
/posts/1/article-title
```

before the comment errors are displayed.  This is working fine for me on my test server, but am I going to run into any particular problems with this second redirect?  I'm asking because the posts/questions I've read are suggesting that TempData needs to be used straight after a redirect.  If it isn't, the data may be lost between requests and I'm wondering if my second redirect could cause that.

Comment: Can you point out which questions you've read that makes you think this?  They'll need to be downvoted or commented on because this has changed since MVC 1.

Comment: I've read an awful lot about TempData lately and I can't seem to find all sources which gave me that impression.  However, one of them I did find again was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968500/how-to-return-model-state-from-child-action-handler-in-asp-net-mvc/2968978#2968978) answer which sent me to [this](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/10/18/storing-modelstate-in-tempdata-with-aspnet-mvc/) blog post.  I'll keep searching through my history to see if I can find the other sources.  There are definitely others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC 2 and 3 TempData is always available to access once.  After you access a given key the temporary data is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had no idea this had changed with newer versions of MVC.